# Transact SQL using WITH in CREATE VIEW

Tags: t-sql, view

I want to create VIEW using WITH clauses, but really can't find any references on correct syntax.

I want smth like this

```
WITH TempTbl AS (SELECT ...)
CREATE VIEW SomeView
SELECT *
FROM TempTbl
```

And what is the correct syntax for using several WITH clauses?

Nothing useful on MSDN :(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The CTE goes inside the view.

Take a query with a CTE

```
WITH cte AS (...) SELECT ...;
```

Just add CREATE VIEW AS .. GO

```
CREATE VIEW
AS
WITH cte AS (...) SELECT ...;
GO
```

[MSDN does describe multiple CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (See example j)

```
CREATE VIEW
AS
WITH
   cte1 AS (...),
   cte2 AS (...),
   cte3 AS (...)
SELECT ...
GO
```

Comment: The trick for me was to remove some extra parentheses. `create view myView as ( select ... )` works and `create view myView as with tempTbl as select ...` works but `create view myView as ( with tempTbl as select ... )` is a syntax error.
`

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE VIEW 
someview
AS
WITH CTEstuff AS (SELECT etc)
SELECT * FROM CTESTuff;
```

Comment: welcome to dba.se and thanks for the contribution. Just so you know, the question here is really too basic for the site and will probably be closed - but that is no reflection on your answer :) Given your skills on SQL Server and postgres there will be plenty more on-topic questions right up your street, so I hope you stick around.

Comment: Btw postgres is awesome! (speaking as an Oracle DBA) I'm sure you agree :)

Comment: Nice to be here. I think it'd be a shame to consider any question too basic; although I agree it might not be an administration question and might belong in a different forum, perhaps stack exchange itself. Anyhoo thanks!

Comment: I think you are right SO is probably best, but we try and be a bit flexible especially if people have already put effort into answering by the time we notice :)